# Android JsonArrayRequest onResponse is never executed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this issue has been bugging me all day. I have stepped through the program with the debugger and it never goes into the Response.Listener. It doesn't go into onErrorResponse either so the API isn't throwing an error.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history_rewards);

    prf = new PrefManager(this);

    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.earning_history);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    TextView emptyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
    emptyText.setText(getString(R.string.no_rewards_yet));
    adapter = new UserHistoryAdapter(EarningHistoryActivity.this, historyList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyText);
    listView.setDivider(null);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    // getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    JsonArrayRequest historyReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.Base_Url+"api/earning_history.php?username="+App.getInstance().getUsername(), new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            UserHistory history = new UserHistory();
                            history.setTitle(obj.getString("type"));
                            history.setRating(obj.getString("date"));
                            history.setThumbnailUrl(Config.Base_Url+"images/reward.png");
                            history.setYear(obj.getString("points"));
                            //history.setGenre(obj.getString("time"));

                            historyList.add(history);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(historyReq);

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I added more code from the entire onCreate method to give some more information to help.

Comment: Does logcat show any error? and post the code to add to the request queue

Comment: @Napster This line is displayed in Logcat: D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: EarningHistoryActivity

Comment: That means it is going in `onErrorResponse`. Your API is throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

You have created historyReq object of class JsonArrayRequest;

Now there should be some method call inside JsonArrayRequest class which make utilize the Response.ErrorListener() object that you injected inside the historyReq. The injected objected inside historyReq should make use of on onErrorResponse method.

For more info you can see behavior of Anonymous class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Java and this is the only part of the application that isn't working properly. This code is directly after the JsonArrayRequest:
    
    // Adding request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(historyReq);

Comment: you should see requestQueue, how it uses the historyReq object. Its difficult to solve without seeing the code. By the given hints you can find out.

Comment: I updated the OP to include the entire onCreate method. Hope that helps

Comment: So you added the object to requestQueue. Its logical that you can get the historyReq object from requestQueue. So there should be some method like get() inside requestQueue object, you can call that to get historyReq object. Once you get the historyReq object you can call some method like get ErrorLIstener().